# Exposing VisualOffsets property

Tags: c#, wpf, uielement

I am making an application in C# WPF and need the location of an object that I added to a panel. While debugging I found the VisualOffset property of the object that gives me the relative position. I just can't get the value from the code.

[image: UserControl object - VisualOffset]

What I would like to do is (though it is not possible):

```
var display = new Display(); // This is a class that inhereit UserControl
.
.
// At some point when display is added to a panel
var position = display.VisualOffset; // This property is not accessible
```

So how can I get the relative position of an object?

Comment: Why don't you create another public property in your UserControl that simply returns the `VisualOffset` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TranslatePoint` method of the `Display` instance. Set the parent control as a target. The code below will give you coordinates of `display` on its parent. If the container is further down the visual tree then you have to find a parent of a parent.

In my sample I'm finding that on the parent. I'm doing that on button click and then return the results as a string to a text box - purely for simplicity sake. But the idea is the same wherever you use it:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = display.Parent as UIElement;
    var location = display.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), parent);

    this.myTextBox.Text = $"x: {location.X}, y: {location.Y}";
}
```

`display` is of course an instance of the `Display` user control.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there a reason why the VisualOffset property exist but can not be accessed?

Comment: a little late here but its explosed via the Visual type, i.e. `(display as Visual).VisualOffset`